# How to make EditText hint not to wrap?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a one line EditText, when I set a long hint, the hint wraps to two lines. Can I force the EditText to be always one line tall? `android:lines="1"` didn't work.

Comment: Why would you want an edittext hint that's longer than the edittext field? I think that just means you hint is too long

Comment: I'm dynamically changing the hint during runtime.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried `android:ellipsize` yet? This can be set to truncate the line to end in "..." either at the start, the middle, the end, or you can set it to marquee (scroll across). Not sure offhand whether this applies to hints or not, but it should.

Comment: `marquee` doesn't application on `EditText`

Comment: `marquee` crashes `EditText` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try    `android:singleLine="true"`

Comment: For some reason, singleLine does not seem to impact the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:maxLines="1"` or `android:singleLine="true"` instead of `android:lines="1"`