# How to set EditText to show suspension points in the last line without cut the text out of bounds

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` view with a bounded size of 300dp * 300dp.

This EditText is used to show a preview of some descriptions received from a server, so if the text is too long appears cut in the last line.
I want that in case of too long text, in the end of the last fully visible line are showed suspension points to avoid bad truncation

example

if for the text

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

If the max visible text is only

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,
```

The EditText should show

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici...
```

Any solutions?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958138/how-to-make-edittext-hint-not-to-wrap?rq=1 You should add elipsize="end" on your edit text.

Answer (score 6):

If your message is a description obtained from a server and it is rather useless to edit it by the user, why not using `TextView` instead?

```
    <TextView
        ...
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

Same you can achieve with `EditText`, but you have to set also `android:editable="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the width of a text using [measureText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29) from the [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) class.
If the text is too long for the view, just search for the substring that fit that width.

For example, if `view` is the `EditText` :

```
String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
String subtext = text;
Paint paint = view.getPaint();

while( paint.measureText(subtext) > view.getWidth() ) {
    subtext = subtext.substring(0, subtext.lastIndexOf(' '));
}

view.setText(subtext + "...");
```